# How to fetch PostgreSQL result in another function?

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I want to return the data which is generated in the PostgreSQL query result of `getData()`function, in console 1 i am getting the expected result but it is unable to access outside the query function i mean in console 2 am getting empty array. it should be able to access in my 2nd function called `getFun()`
i want to get the console 1 value from `getData()` to `getFun()`.
 can some one help me please.
Here is my code:

```
 function getData(value){
    var array = [];
     db.query('select * from users where _id = $1', [value], function(err, result) {
      array.push(result.rows);
    console.log('1',array);
    })
    console.log('2', array);
    }

    exports.getFun = function(data, callback) {
     employee.find({
                    'company_id':parseInt(data.company_id)
                }).sort({
                    "times.date": -1
                }).toArray().then(function(timers) {
               _.each(timers.list, function(s) {
               var display = getData(s.user_id);
               console.log('3',display);
                })

                }).catch(function(error) {
                    console.log(error);
                })
    }
```

Comment: you run `db.query` async, so `var array` is probably populated later then you c`console.log` it ?..

Comment: In `getFun()` i will get the particular `user_id` then `getData() by passig `s.user_id` as a parameter so getData() function has to be called and get the details from PostgreSQL db and return